# SWT on OS X: NSSheet equivalent

Tags: macos, swt

Is SWT capable of showing an NSSheet like [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/jsheet.html) simulates it using Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to create the `Dialog` with the option `SWT.SHEET`, e.g.

```
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.SHEET);
```